# CWebApplication.... is not defined

Tags: php, yii

I've been trying to include something on my Yii extension

```
'components' => array(
    'ExcelExporter' => array(
        'class' => 'application.extensions.webcomum.components.ExcelExporter.excelExporter',
    )`
```

I'm trying to call this class like this:

```
$request = Survey::model()->findAll();
Yii::app()->ExcelExporter->exporter($request);
```

the Class/method header is

```
class ExcelExporter extends CApplicationComponent {
public static function exporter($sqlRequest) {
...
}
}
```

The path I'm using on the config/main.php is correct.
What am I missing?

Everything works if I just include the class.

All help is appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Edit:
I tried removing the static and calling the method the same way I'm showing above, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Yii::app()` is it valid ie is it returning a valid object. Also `exporter` is declared static and you are calling it using `->`.

Is the case correct here...

```
class excelExporter {
```

Should this be

```
class ExcelExporter {
```

Normally components also inherit from one of the Yii classes ie

```
class ExcelExporter extends CApplicationComponent {
```

Comment: Yes, Yii::app() returns a valid object.
I fixed the excel to Excel like you said, and I also put the extends ....  but the error still shows.
How should I be calling the static method?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my pathing and where I put my code... I was calling it on the backend but the code was on the frontend...
Thank you for the help :)